# Google fonts displayed on desktop but not on mobile (Tested on Android an iOS)

Tags: css, modx, google-fonts

I am redesign a website for a client (Using MODX CMS) [here](https://www.dev.stephan-fuhrer.ch/) and I am using 2 different Google fonts.

I can display them on desktop but not on mobile.

I tried on Chrome for Android and Safari on iOS.

On desktop (Mac and Windows) it works properly (with different browsers).

Am I linking them wrong?

Here what I have in CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Zilla+Slab:300,300i,400,400i,500,500i,600,600i,700,700i');

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit:400,400i,500,500i,600,700,800');

body {
font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif !important;
}

h1 {
font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #e63f2f;
font-size: 20px;
}

h2 {
font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
text-transform: uppercase;
color: #e63f2f;
}
```

What I tried is also deactivating the module MinifyX but nothing change.

Any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To link in the following two fonts in **CSS**, do the following:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Zilla+Slab');

font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;


@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit');

font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
```

Or by **HTML**:

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Zilla+Slab" rel="stylesheet">

font-family: 'Zilla Slab', serif;


<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Kanit" rel="stylesheet">

font-family: 'Kanit', sans-serif;
```